# Is there a way to force older versions of Excel Api (api version<=1.1) to fit column width to content?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, excel-addins

I'm currently working on an Addin for Excel, I use Javascript and JQuery in the code, and I am using the latest version of the Office JS library by the date of this question. 
The issue I'm facing is a compatibility issue as the `sheet.getUsedRange().format.autofitColumns();` line works with Excel versions that have ExcelApi 1.2 or later, but I can't manage to do the same thing with earlier versions, is there a workaround to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

The availability of APIs is based on the native C++ code of the host.  For an API like `autofitColumns()` -- and pretty much any other APIs that weren't part of the original ExcelApi 1.1 offering of Office 2016 -- that unfortunately means that there is no workaround.  You can specify the requirement sets in your manifest, and/or do dynamic checks for `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported(...)` for a light-up scenario, but there is nothing you can do to make an API work if the host doesn't support it.

Comment: I have the version check implemented, thank you for your answer though!